# Color specific cells that if array has corresponding values

Tags: javascript, arrays

I'm trying to color all cells with yellow color corresponding to array values. For example in the picture below all numbers 1-12 are clickable and have their own function.

When I click 1 the function generates 4 numbers from 1-25 and stores it in array. Let's say the numbers are 2,5,8,10. So cells 2,5,8,10 should be colored in yellow. How to color the cells corresponding to the array values.

My cells have ids representing their value. So id of number 1 is '1' and so on. I can't think of any way.

```js
function func1() {
  var random = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 20, 21, 22, 23, 24, 25];
  var selection = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12];
  var numbers = [];
  for (i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
    var randomPositionl = Math.floor(Math.random() * random.length);
    var final = random.splice(randomPositionl, 1);
    console.log(final);
  }
}

function func2() {
  console.log(2);
}


function func3() {
  console.log(3);
}

function func4() {
  console.log(4);
}

function func5() {
  console.log(5);
}

function func6() {
  console.log(6);
}

function func7() {
  console.log(7);
}

function func8() {
  console.log(8);
}

function func9() {
  console.log(9);
}

function func10() {
  console.log(10);
}

function func11() {
  console.log(11);
}

function func12() {
  console.log(12);
}
```

```css
table {
  font-family: arial, sans-serif;
  font-size: 16px;
  border-collapse: collapse;
  width: 100%;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
  table-layout: fixed;
  text-align: center;
  cursor: pointer;
  color: white;
  float: left;
  text-shadow: 2px 2px 4px #000000;
  background-color: black;
}

td {
  border: 2px #a49e9b solid;
}

td:hover {
  background-color: yellow;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
  <title>JS Bin</title>
</head>

<body>
  <table cellpadding="15" cellspacing="15">
    <tr>
      <td id="1" onclick="func1()">1</td>
      <td id="3" onclick="func3()">3</td>
      <td id="5" onclick="func5()">5</td>
      <td id="7" onclick="func7()">7</td>
      <td id="9" onclick="func9()">9</td>
      <td id="11" onclick="func11()">11</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td id="2" onclick="func2()">2</td>
      <td id="4" onclick="func4()">4</td>
      <td id="6" onclick="func6()">6</td>
      <td id="8" onclick="func8()">8</td>
      <td id="10" onclick="func10()">10</td>
      <td id="12" onclick="func12()">12</td>
    </tr>
  </table>
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```js
const previous = [];
function func1() {
  var random = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 20, 21, 22, 23, 24, 25];
  var selection = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12];
  var numbers = [];
  previous.map(n =>{
    const e = document.querySelector(`#id${n}`);
    if(!e || !e.style ) return;
     e.style.removeProperty('background') ;});
previous.length = 0;

  for (i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
    var randomPositionl = Math.floor(Math.random() * random.length);
    var n =random[randomPositionl];
    
    previous.push(n);
    const e = document.querySelector(`#id${n}`);
    if(!e || !e.style) continue;
     e.style.setProperty('background', 'yellow');
    
  }
}

function func2() {
  console.log(2);
}


function func3() {
  console.log(3);
}

function func4() {
  console.log(4);
}

function func5() {
  console.log(5);
}

function func6() {
  console.log(6);
}

function func7() {
  console.log(7);
}

function func8() {
  console.log(8);
}

function func9() {
  console.log(9);
}

function func10() {
  console.log(10);
}

function func11() {
  console.log(11);
}

function func12() {
  console.log(12);
}
```

```css
table {
  font-family: arial, sans-serif;
  font-size: 16px;
  border-collapse: collapse;
  width: 100%;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
  table-layout: fixed;
  text-align: center;
  cursor: pointer;
  color: white;
  float: left;
  text-shadow: 2px 2px 4px #000000;
  background-color: black;
}

td {
  border: 2px #a49e9b solid;
}

td:hover {
  background-color: yellow;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
  <title>JS Bin</title>
</head>

<body>
  <table cellpadding="15" cellspacing="15">
    <tr>
      <td id="id1" onclick="func1()">1</td>
      <td id="id3" onclick="func3()">3</td>
      <td id="id5" onclick="func5()">5</td>
      <td id="id7" onclick="func7()">7</td>
      <td id="id9" onclick="func9()">9</td>
      <td id="id11" onclick="func11()">11</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td id="id2" onclick="func2()">2</td>
      <td id="id4" onclick="func4()">4</td>
      <td id="id6" onclick="func6()">6</td>
      <td id="id8" onclick="func8()">8</td>
      <td id="id10" onclick="func10()">10</td>
      <td id="id12" onclick="func12()">12</td>
    </tr>
  </table>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Please comment and tell us what the code improves!

Comment: @Steward Please can you say what this code does that at all matches what you asked for?

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps you meant this?

I think you have too many arrays here

```js
const tb = document.getElementById("tb");
const cells = tb.querySelectorAll("td")
tb.addEventListener("click",func)

function func(e) {
  tgt = e.target;
  
  var final = []
  var numbers = [];
  for (i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
    var randomPositionl = Math.floor(Math.random() * cells.length);
    final.push(randomPositionl);
  }
    console.log(final);
  const num = +tgt.id; 
  console.log(num)
  cells.forEach((cell,i) => cell.classList.toggle("yellow",final.includes(i)))

}
```

```css
table {
  font-family: arial, sans-serif;
  font-size: 16px;
  border-collapse: collapse;
  width: 100%;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
  table-layout: fixed;
  text-align: center;
  cursor: pointer;
  color: white;
  float: left;
  text-shadow: 2px 2px 4px #000000;
  background-color: black;
}

td {
  border: 2px #a49e9b solid;
}

td:hover {
  background-color: yellow;
}

.yellow {
  background-color: yellow;
}
```

```html
<table cellpadding="15" cellspacing="15">
  <tbody id="tb">
    <tr>
      <td id="1">1</td>
      <td id="3">3</td>
      <td id="5">5</td>
      <td id="7">7</td>
      <td id="9">9</td>
      <td id="11">11</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td id="2">2</td>
      <td id="4">4</td>
      <td id="6">6</td>
      <td id="8">8</td>
      <td id="10">10</td>
      <td id="12">12</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Answer (score 0):

I will propose you another way to implement that .

```
function func1(td) {
  let randomColor = Math.floor(Math.random()*16777215).toString(16); // hexa code
  td.style.backgroundColor = randomColor ;  // fixing td background color 
  
}
```

And update your html with this :

```
<table cellpadding="15" cellspacing="15">
<tr>
  <td id="1" onclick="func1(this)">1</td>
  <td id="3" onclick="func3(this)">3</td>
  <td id="5" onclick="func5(this)">5</td>
  <td id="7" onclick="func7(this)">7</td>
  <td id="9" onclick="func9(this)">9</td>
  <td id="11" onclick="func11(this)">11</td>
</tr>
<tr>
  <td id="2" onclick="func2(this)">2</td>
  <td id="4" onclick="func4(this)">4</td>
  <td id="6" onclick="func6(this)">6</td>
  <td id="8" onclick="func8(this)">8</td>
  <td id="10" onclick="func10(this)">10</td>
  <td id="12" onclick="func12(this)">12</td>
</tr>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can always grab your square selectors using `querySelectorAll()` and then get their keys and place them into an array. Then run that array of index values into a helper function that will return 4 random indexes. Then check those indexes in a loop over the index array to get matching elements with those indexes and set their background-color to yellow.

```js
const cont = document.querySelector('.grid-container')
const squares = cont.querySelectorAll('.squares')

const index = []
for (const key of squares.keys()) {
  index.push(key);
}
// helper function to return random unique values into an array
const getRan = (arr, count) => {
  let temp = arr.slice(arr);
  let ret = []
  // lets get unique values that will never match out of the array
  for (let i = 0; i < count; i++) {
    let index = Math.floor(Math.random() * temp.length);
    let removed = temp.splice(index, 1);
    ret.push(removed[0]);
  }
  return ret;
}

let turn = true;
squares.forEach(sq => {
  sq.addEventListener('click', function() {
    if (turn !== false) {
      getRan(index, 4).forEach(num => {
        console.log(num)
        squares[num].style.backgroundColor = 'yellow'
        turn = false;
      })
    }
  })
})
```

```css
.grid-container {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr 1fr 1fr;
  grid-template-rows: 1fr 1fr 1fr 1fr;
  gap: 0px 0px;
  width: 120px;
  height: 120px;
  grid-template-areas: "three six nine twelve" "two five eight eleven" "one four seven ten" "first first first first";
}

.squares {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  border: solid 1px grey;
  color: white;
  background-color: black;
}

.squares:nth-child(odd) {
  background-color: red;
}

.one {
  grid-area: one;
}

.two {
  grid-area: two;
}

.three {
  grid-area: three;
}

.four {
  grid-area: four;
}

.five {
  grid-area: five;
}

.six {
  grid-area: six;
}

.seven {
  grid-area: seven;
}

.eight {
  grid-area: eight;
}

.nine {
  grid-area: nine;
}

.ten {
  grid-area: ten;
}

.eleven {
  grid-area: eleven;
}

.twelve {
  grid-area: twelve;
}

.first {
  grid-area: first;
}
```

```html
<div class="grid-container">
  <div data-id="1" class="squares one">1</div>
  <div data-id="2" class="squares two">2</div>
  <div data-id="3" class="squares three">3</div>
  <div data-id="4" class="squares four">4</div>
  <div data-id="5" class="squares five">5</div>
  <div data-id="6" class="squares six">6</div>
  <div data-id="7" class="squares seven">7</div>
  <div data-id="8" class="squares eight">8</div>
  <div data-id="9" class="squares nine">9</div>
  <div data-id="10" class="squares ten">10</div>
  <div data-id="11" class="squares eleven">11</div>
  <div data-id="12" class="squares twelve">12</div>
  <div class="first"></div>
</div>
```